# How to set headers to application/json in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, post, header

I am trying to send HTTP post request in Angular 2 but not able to set headers to content type application JSON.

**My code is:**

```
login(url,postdata)
{
    var headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this._http.post(url,JSON.stringify(postdata),this.headers)
    .map(res => res.json())    
}
```

When I checked in network I found that `Content-Type` is set as `text/plain` and thus server is not receiving any data.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Join the chat had some similar issues ....

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144381/angular-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private _getHeaders():Headers {
   let header = new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });

   return header;
}



public login(url, postdata){
   let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: this._getHeaders()
   });
   return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(postdata),options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Not able to set headers still.Actually on sending post request to server payload is not getting send.I checked content-type in network and its text/plain instead of application/json.                   
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:35
content-type:text/plain

Answer (score 4):

change `_http.post` parameters :

```
login(url,postdata) {
    var headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this._http.post(url,postdata,{headers:headers})
                .map(res => res.json())    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Referencing the Angular 2 [Angular Http Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request) @angular/http has been deprecated, and @angular/common/http should be the one you are using in your Angular 2 App. Because if you do not specify http headers the default request will be sent as Content-Type text/plain, How you modify the http headers is to:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
.....
const req = this.http.post('/api/PostRequest/',
                            JSON.stringify(object),
                            {
                             headers:new HttpHeaders()
                             .set('Content-Type','application/json')
                             }).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use code like this

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(postdata), options).map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular 9 version for 2020

```
export class ApiService {

  private headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}${path}`, {params, headers: this.headers});
  }
}
```