# Ionic 3 http post - reading body data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to send a http post body data. It worked well with angular but now I am using ionic. Any help is appreciated.

```
let newMember = {
    "sendData": [{
            name: "first_name",
            val: "mike"
               },
        {
            name: "last_name",
            val: "tester"
               },
        {
            name: "city",
            val: "new york"
               },
        {
            name: "state",
            val: "NY"
               },
        {
            name: "zip",
            val: "10001"
               }]
}

let body = new FormData();
body.append('newMember', JSON.stringify(newMember));


 this.http.post('https://data.testme.com/setup',newMember,{headers: headers
    }, body)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

This is how I am trying to send it to a nodejs server.

My nodejs sever it getting this in the body.

```
console.log("sendData req.body --> " , req.body);

   {sendData: [{
            name: 'first_name',
            val: 'mike'
               },
        {
            name: 'last_name',
            val: 'tester'
               },
        {
            name: 'city',
            val: 'new york'
               },
        {
            name: 'state',
            val: 'NY'
               },
        {
            name: 'zip',
            val: '10001'
               }]
    }
```

I found this in my out log. I was looking at my error logs before. Showing error because it could read:

```
 var newMember = req.body.newMember;
```

**How do I read newMember in Node.js ??**

Thanks
Phil

Comment: what headers are you allowing in node? are you using cors()?

Comment: Also can you please share the route and how you have set it up in node something like app.post() or router.route() .post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mismatch parameters. see [documentation](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#post)

try this

```
this.http.post('https://data.testme.com/setup', body, {
        headers: headers
    })
```

Comment: you were correct I did have the body in the wrong place. Now how do I read the json data on nodejs.

Comment: @philipfwilson problem is that you are not sending json, its form data to set header look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006844/how-to-set-headers-to-application-json-in-angular2 .

Comment: @philipfwilson now you can be proud ;)

Answer (score 0):

and add plugin 
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

```
this.http.post(https://data.testme.com/setup/', newMember).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                     console.log('error'+data); 
                     },err => {
                       console.log('error'+err); 
                    });
```